# React-Native built app uses old images

Tags: android, react-native

I have a strange bug when building my app(Android). I had an image I used as an icon in a screen of my app. I then swapped it out for a different image(same name). After building my app (gradlew assembleRelease) I noticed that the image did not change. I tried swapping the image several times. No difference. Other changes to the app did reflect on build. Deleting the image resulted in a build failure(as expected).

Comment: try `./gradlew clean` before `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: Thanks that worked. I thought it was weird since the image is not in the android dir. IF you can make your comment into an answer i will mark it.

Comment: you're welcome =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `./gradlew clean` before `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

Generally it solved this problem for me.